# Pattern recognition in 2D dataset

Tags: python, r, data-mining, dataset, algorithms

I'm not familiar with the ways and tools of data scientists but I have a background in software engineering and mathematics. I'd need to recognize patterns in a two-dimensional data set. I have a lot of measurements of a valve's power consumption over time. The valve is under test. I'd need to tell based on the measurements if the valve is working properly or not. I have sample measurements of properly working and not properly working valves. This is a custom valve so it has no datasheet. I think I could start investigating this on my own but some insight from you would be really great. For example, what are some good tools I can use to analyze the data? Is there any recommended standard way of doing this? Are there any good references I could follow? Thank you.

Comment: As a software engineer learning some data science, you might want to check out the great course offered (for free!) by [fast.ai](http://course.fast.ai/).